# Prove Legitimate Windows User Logged In (not live disk access)

Tags: windows, security

How you go about proving to a script/program that the user executing it is legitimate? You could grab user name/id, but if the hard drive is taken by Bob, and spun up in a new machine is there anything stopping Bob creating a user with the same name/id and fooling the program to thinking its legitimate?

Does windows have a public key or anything similar for a user?

Essentially I want to automate a script to run a startup, but only after the (and only) legitimate user has signed in. I want to prevent someone taking the script from the machine, and executing it in a different environment that fools the script into thinking a legitimate user is logged in.

As usual apologies if this duplicates, I think I'm searching with the wrong keywords because I can't find what I'm looking for.

I mention script because ideally I'll implement it in Python, but the language isn't important for the answer.

Edit: More googling suggests that there is a Windows User security id (SID) and also access tokens. So perhaps I can lock the script down to a specific SID, and verify that the script is started with a valid access token? But would it be possible to get the SID off the system and create a new user with the same SID and fake access?

Also, I'm starting to think this needs to be moved to the security stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not an exact answer to my question, but solves the overall problem.

The Windows [Crypt.ProtectData()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261(v=vs.85).aspx) API encrypts data so that only the user that created it can decrypt it.

By encrypting and writing to a file, I can store things which don't need an extra password to access, and can reasonably assume only the user can access. The data will not be readable by anyone using a livedisk or moving the files into another Windows environment with the same windows User name.

To answer the original question more directly, by testing if you can decrypt it, you are proving that the intended user is running the code.

As I mentioned in the original question, I wanted to script this in python. So I wrote a class to store/retrieve key:value pairs from an encrypted file using pywin32 and `win32Crypt.ProtectData()`. I posted it on [GitHub](https://github.com/tantalum7/WCS) for anyone interested.